# MongoDB aggregation performance issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB for my Nodejs project and when using the below piece of code with aggregation the performance seems to be very slow.

```
masterSchema.hotelDetails.aggregate({
$match: {
    "hotel.basicInfo.city.id": cityId.toString()
}
}, {
$sort: {
    "hotel.basicInfo.district.name": -1
}
}, {
$group: {
    _id: "$hotel.basicInfo.district.id",
    name: {
        $first: "$hotel.basicInfo.district.name"
    }
}
}).exec(function(err, enData) {
if(err) {
    console.log(err);
}
for(var i in enData) {
    for(var j in filterObj.district) {
        if(filterObj.district[j]._id === enData[i]._id) {
            filterObj.district[j].en = (enData[i].name !== null) ? enData[i].name : "Others";
            break;
        }
    }
}
   callback();
 });
```

> `I COMMAND  [conn13994] command production.hotelDetailsAr command: aggregate { aggregate: "hotelDetailsAr", pipeline: [ { $match: { hotel.basicInfo.city.id: "54350" } }, { $sort: { hotel.basicInfo.district.name: -1 } }, { $group: { _id: "$hotel.basicInfo.district.id", districtCount: { $sum: 1 }, name: { $first: "$hotel.basicInfo.district.name" } } } ] } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:1129 reslen:112 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2264 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1132 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1132 } } } protocol:op_query 802ms`

```
filterQuery.aggregate({
        $match: {
            "hotel.basicInfo.city.id": cityId.toString()
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            0: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [{
                        $eq: ["$hotel.basicInfo.starRating", "5"]
                    }, 1, 0]
                }
            },
            1: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [{
                        $eq: ["$hotel.basicInfo.starRating", "4"]
                    }, 1, 0]
                }
            },
            2: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [{
                        $eq: ["$hotel.basicInfo.starRating", "3"]
                    }, 1, 0]
                }
            },
            3: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [{
                        $eq: ["$hotel.basicInfo.starRating", "2"]
                    }, 1, 0]
                }
            },
            4: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [{
                        $eq: ["$hotel.basicInfo.starRating", "1"]
                    }, 1, 0]
                }
            },
            5: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [{
                        $eq: ["$hotel.basicInfo.starRating", "0"]
                    }, 1, 0]
                }
            },
            6: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [{
                        $eq: ["$hotel.basicInfo.starRating", null]
                    }, 1, 0]
                }
            }


        }
    }).exec(function (err, data) {
        filterObj.starRating = data;
        callback();
    });
```

**Server information:**

- Centos 5
- 8 Core CPU
- 40GB RAM

**MongoDB Info**

- 240,370 Documents
- 480MB
- Version 3.2

Am i doing something wrong with the query?

Comment: Do you have an [index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) on `hotel.basicInfo.city.id` ? What's the purpose of posting the second aggregation query ? How many documents matched the `city.id`? First aggregation is currently takes less than 1 second (802ms), what's your desired speed ?

Comment: @WanBachtiar yes i have index for `hotel.basicInfo.city.id`, and a total of 3282 document matched with the given `city.id`. **(802ms)** is quite a huge time when it comes to more concurrency in the future.

Comment: How big is the size of your average documents ? All three of the aggregations you posted are different. I'd suggest to edit your question for clarification, a) choose 1 aggregation b) remove your forEach for debugging c) removing node.js out of the equation for now d) analyse [aggregation explain output](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#return-information-on-aggregation-pipeline-operation). Is this a standalone deployment ? What's the memory usage utilisation in the machine ?